# Cannot add foreign key mysql error 1215

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm pretty new to mysql, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong...
I'm using mysql workbench and

```
$ mysql -V

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I tried indexing the foreign keys but nothing.

```
create table Prodotti(
    ProdottoID int not null auto_increment,
    Descrizione nvarchar(50) not null,
    PrezzoUnitario decimal not null,
    RicavoUnitario decimal not null,
    constraint PK_Prodotti primary key(ProdottoID)
)ENGINE=INNODB; 

create table Ingredienti(
    IngredienteID int not null auto_increment,
    Descrizione nvarchar(50) not null,
    Giacenza int not null,
    CostoUnitario decimal not null,
    UnitaDiMisura nvarchar(45) not null,
    constraint PK_Ingredienti primary key(IngredienteID)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

create table Prodotti_Ingredienti(
    ProdottoID int not null,
    IngredienteID int not null,
    Quantita decimal not null,
    UnitaDiMisura nvarchar(45) not null,
    constraint FK_Prod_Ing_prodottoid foreign key(ProdottoID) references     Prodotti(ProdottoID)
        on delete cascade
    on update cascade,  
constraint FK_Prod_Ing_ingredienteidunitamisura foreign key(IngredienteID,UnitaDiMisura) references     Ingredienti(IngredienteID,UnitaDiMisura)
        on update cascade,
    constraint PK_Prod_Ing primary key(ProdottoID,IngredienteID)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the referenced key, which is a composite one:

```
... references Ingredienti(IngredienteID, UnitaDiMisura)
```

According to the MySQL [**documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

You can create such an index using the following statement:

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON Ingredienti (IngredienteID, UnitaDiMisura);
```

**However**, you should be careful as to what this FK really implements. Since the *composite* key `(IngredienteID, UnitaDiMisura)` is not the PK of table `Ingredienti`, nor is it a unique index, you might end up in *multiple* references to `Ingredienti` table for the `(IngredienteID, UnitaDiMisura)` value.

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL Manual:

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

This means that you need to have an index for IngredienteID,UnitaDiMisura) in table Ingredienti, or it will not work.